# facebook graph api call to post image using servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post image to user wall using javascript FB.api. Image is generated from a java servlet dynamically, but due to asynchronous behavior before the image is generated it passes control below the block to post image to Facebook part. 
I want either

1. how can I make fb.api post to Facebook call from servlet?
2. how to deal with this behavior so that control will not passes below before image generation?

**note** servlet is working file and generating image .

```
var imgURL="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/myapps/app1?monthly="+monthly+"&recent="+recent+"&likes="+likes;

//var imgURL="http://xxx.2xx.xx6.1x8:8084/WebApplication6/image";
alert('image');
//var imgURL="https://graph.facebook.com/100000329585395/picture";
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src =imgURL;
document.body.appendChild(img);


FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
message:'image',
url:imgURL        
                       }, function(response){
                           alert('here');

if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured'+response.error);
} else {
    var postId = response.id;
     alert(postId);}


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [RESTFB](http://restfb.com/) Api which is a Java API. You can use this instead of Javascript API.